# Julia Genie routing unexpected end of input

Tags: rest, http, julia, http-status-code-500, genie.jl

I keep getting this error :

> ######################### ERROR STACKTRACE #########################
> Expected end of input
> Line: 0
> Around: ...11092×16 DataFrame    Row...

But when I run the code (excluding the routes) in a separate terminal, it runs just fine, returning a DataFrame of securities symbols with some information about them.

What am I doing wrong? (*Note that the api key published here is a publishable key that only has access to free data.*)

```
using Genie, Genie.Renderer.Json, Genie.Requests
using HTTP, JSON
using DataFrames

route("/tickers", method = POST) do
  message = jsonpayload()
#  (:echo => (message["message"] * " ") ^ message["repeat"]) |> json
    syms = HTTP.request("GET","https://acre.iex.cloud/v1/data/CORE/REF_DATA?token=pk_79891f5cbcce4099ae063588956f937a")
    schema_req = HTTP.request("GET","https://acre.iex.cloud/v1/data/CORE/REF_DATA?schema=true&token=pk_79891f5cbcce4099ae063588956f937a")
    sbs = syms.body |> String |> JSON.parse
    smat = sbs .|> values .|> collect |> (x->reduce(hcat,x)) |> (x->permutedims(DataFrame(x,:auto)))
    schema = schema_req.body |> String |> JSON.parse |> first |> keys |> collect
    rename!(smat,Symbol.(schema))
end

route("/send") do
  response = HTTP.request("POST", "http://localhost:8000/tickers", [("Content-Type", "application/json")], """{"exchanges":"XNYS", "type":"cs"}""")
  response.body |> String |> JSON.parse
end

up(async = false)
```

Ultimately, I'd like the  '/tickers' route to be an API backend and the `/send` route to exist in a desktop application (not necessarily as a webpage), so answers without relying heavily on formatting the `/send` route are very welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace of the erro?

Comment: Also, just in case you weren't aware, the best place to get Genie support is (unfortunately) their Discord server, which is linked on the Genie website.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that importing both `JSON` and `Genie.Renderer.Json` overloads the name `json`, and I need to use Genie's json parse method for `response.body`, so I need to specify  `json` as `Genie.Renderer.Json.json`.

Hence the `/send` route should look like:

```
route("/send") do
  response = HTTP.request("POST", "http://localhost:8000/tickers", [("Content-Type", "application/json")], """{"exchanges":"XNYS", "type":"cs"}""")
  response.body |> String |> Genie.Renderer.Json.json
end
```

The output looks really ugly though, so I'd like a way to change that.